# How to access Kendo.Grid() row ID when calling server method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have the `Kendo Grid`. It has a number of columns and one of that is `ID` column. I'm looking for the way to send this ID to the controller on `Destroy` event.

This is the Grid:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TicketReportPropertyEntity>()
    .Name("TicketReportPropertyGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(c => c.PropertyName).Title("Property Name").EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor").Width(900);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Amount).Title("Amount").Format("{0:C}").Width(90);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Destroy();
        }).Width(250);
    })
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Create();
            toolbar.Save();
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).ConfirmDelete("Are you sure").DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Delete"))
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("Databound").SaveChanges("SaveGrid").Edit("Edit"))
        .DataSource(datasource => datasource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
        //.PageSize(20)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(c => c.ID);
                model.Field(c => c.PropertyName);
                model.Field(c => c.Amount);
            })
        //.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "TicketReportProperty", Model))
            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateTicketReportProperty", "TicketReportProperty"))
            .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("DeleteTicketReportProperty", "TicketReportProperty"))
        )
)
```

How can I send ID value to the controller on `Destroy` event?

Comment: Are you sure it is not send or do you get an empty value in your controller? Your browser's network console shows you what is sent to the controller. You've defined the {{ID}} as the id of your model, that should do the trick. Why did you add the {{ID}} to your columns? If I am not mistaken you can remove it without any consequences.

Answer (score 0):

The destroy event called in your "DeleteTicketReportProperty" should have functionality to remove the TicketReportProperty.  You shouldn't need to pass it into that except by passing in the view model into the method.
As Carsten Franke said you do not need to put the ID field as a value in your table just pass the ViewModel into your method and then delete the corresponding Model based on that ViewModel ID.

```
_yourDb.Delete(viewModel.ID);
```